# Vue2 - Convert Vanilla ONKEYPRESS Function To Method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to limit the amount of characters entered on a `content editable` div.

This works correctly...

```
<div onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length >= 140 ? false : true )">
```

However, I need to run this as a Vue method (in single file component). I'm trying to do the following, but can't get it to work:

```
<div @keypress="limitTextChar">

// data
props: {
    limitText: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    limitLength: {
        type: Number,
        default: 140
    }
}

limitTextChar(event) {
    return this.limitText && event.target.innerText.length >= this.limitLength ? false : true
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

***JSBIN of the full component:***
https://jsbin.com/pezetuxecu/edit?js

Comment: You have a prop and a method with the same name.

Comment: Sorry, I changed that for this post (for readability). I'll edit.

Comment: I'm not sure the `return` value controls the default behaviour like it would with a native `on*` attribute. You'll probably want to execute `event.preventDefault()` based on your conditional logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to call `preventDefault()` on the event based on your logic. For example

```
limitTextChar(event) {
  if (this.limitText && event.target.innerText.length >= this.limitLength) {
    event.preventDefault()
  }
}
```

---

Another thing to note is that props must be kebab-cased when used in a non-string template, ie instead of

```
<editable :limitText="true"...
```

it should be

```
<editable :limit-text="true"
```

Demo ~ https://jsfiddle.net/yo5o0vwt/

Comment: I considered (and tested exact same function), however it wasn't playing well with `contenteditable` and it's difficult to re-init the `contenteditable` functionality (i.e. delete keys). Caret was also bouncing to the front. Again, it's not playing nice. lol

Comment: Here's a JS Bin of the SFC...if you were inclined to test. https://jsbin.com/pezetuxecu/edit?js

Comment: Note Vue offers a modifier to the `@keypress` syntax to achieve this more cleanly - `@keypress.prevent=""`.

Comment: @Marty that would disable all functionality, and you wouldn't be able to type at all.

Comment: @MikeBarwick I found your real problem :)

Comment: lol really? I've been coding with camel Vue props for a while...without issue. Hmmm

Comment: God damn lol Got some work ahead of me at sunrise...thanks or your help! Going to do test this out soon and will accept after. Agh... https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case

Comment: You need to use kebab-case when the template is an in DOM template. If you use a string template or a single file component, then you can use camel-case. It's a bit confusing if you haven't run into it before.

Comment: Hmm, it's being used in a SFC.

Comment: @MikeBarwick it's to do with the template that includes your component element if that makes any difference. If that is a DOM template (like in my JSFiddle), then it needs to use kebab-case